Despite having checked the addresses containing verified contracts, no contract code at given address
I have token swapping code. Despite having checked the addresses containing verified contracts I get an no contract code at given address error.
The debug data is:
router0 0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D
router1 0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F
token0 0x46101FBe580940C7DD2D2879662bC98954B5edd1
token1 0x46101FBe580940C7DD2D2879662bC98954B5edd1

Checking these addresses on Etherscan show verified contracts.
https://etherscan.io/address/0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D
https://etherscan.io/address/0xd9e1cE17f2641f24aE83637ab66a2cca9C378B9F
https://etherscan.io/address/0x46101FBe580940C7DD2D2879662bC98954B5edd1

Any idea why this happens?
This is the code
package radar

import (
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/api"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/connection"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/constants"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/db"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/helpers"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/mail"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/runtime"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/structures"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/txconftime"
    "arbitrage-bot-v2/wallets"
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/abi/bind"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/common"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/core/types"
    "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto"
    "github.com/jimlawless/whereami"
    "log"
    "math/big"
    "strings"
)

func swap(radarSwap structures.RadarSwap) {
    fmt.Println(radarSwap.Source.DexName, "-->", radarSwap.Destination.DexName, "*************", radarSwap.Source.Token.Address, "-->", radarSwap.Destination.Token.Address)
    if constants.EmailSwapData {
        mapVals := fmt.Sprintf("myGlobalMap: %+v", myGlobalMap)
        //fmt.Println(mapVals)
        total += radarSwap.Profit
        body := helpers.StructToString(radarSwap, "") + "\n" + mapVals
        subject := "$" + fmt.Sprintf("%f", radarSwap.Profit) + " SWAP " + "$" + fmt.Sprintf("%f", total) + " total"
        mail.Send(subject, body)
    }
    if radarSwap.Source.DexPosition == radarSwap.Destination.DexPosition {
        body := "radarSwap.Source.DexPosition == radarSwap.Destination.DexPosition"
        mail.Send("Error", body)
        fmt.Println(body)
        return
    }
    wallet := wallets.Wallet{}
    if constants.UseSingleWallet {
        wallet = wallets.CurrentWalletMap[0]
    } else {
        wallet = wallets.CurrentWalletMap[radarSwap.Source.DexPosition]
    }

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA(wallet.PrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Invalid private key: %v", err)
    }

    chainID, err := connection.Get().NetworkID(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to fetch network ID: %v", err)
    }

    auth, err := bind.NewKeyedTransactorWithChainID(privateKey, chainID)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to create authorized transactor: %v", err)
    }

    slippageTolerancePctInt := big.NewInt(constants.SlippageTolerancePctInt)
    deadlineSecs := new(big.Int)
    _, success := deadlineSecs.SetString(txconftime.Current.TimeSecs, 10)
    if !success {
        body := "Failed to convert string to big.Int"
        mail.Send("Error", body)
        fmt.Println(body)
        deadlineSecs = big.NewInt(constants.DeadlineSecs)
    }

    //_router0, _router1, _token0, _token1, _amount, _slippageTolerancePctInt, _deadlineSecs, _destination
    router0 := common.HexToAddress(radarSwap.Source.DexRouter)
    fmt.Println("router0", router0.Hex())
    router1 := common.HexToAddress(radarSwap.Destination.DexRouter)
    fmt.Println("router1", router1.Hex())
    token0 := common.HexToAddress(radarSwap.Source.Token.Address)
    fmt.Println("token0", token0.Hex())
    token1 := common.HexToAddress(radarSwap.Destination.Token.Address)
    fmt.Println("token1", token1.Hex())
    destination := common.HexToAddress(constants.KrakenVaultAddress)
    fmt.Println("destination", destination.Hex())
    amount := radarSwap.TotalSupply
    fmt.Println("amount", amount)

    contractAddress := common.HexToAddress(wallet.SwapContractAddress)
    var transaction *types.Transaction
    if constants.APIFlashLoanReceiver {
        instance, err := api.NewFlashloanReceiver(contractAddress, connection.Get())
        if err != nil {
            body := "Failed to bind to Base contract:" + err.Error()
            mail.Send("Error", body)
            fmt.Println(body)
            return
        }
        parsedAbi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(`[{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_owner","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"initiator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"baseTokenAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"amount","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"fee","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"onFlashLoan","outputs":[{"internalType":"bytes32","name":"","type":"bytes32"}],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"owner","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"newOwner","type":"address"}],"name":"updateOwner","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"}]`))
        if err != nil {
            body := "Failed to parse ABI:" + err.Error()
            mail.Send("Error", body)
            fmt.Println(body)
            return
        }

        packedData, err := parsedAbi.Pack("onFlashLoan", router0, token0, amount, big.NewInt(constants.APIFlashLoanReceiverFee), []byte(""))
        if err != nil {
            body := "Failed to pack parameters:" + err.Error() + whereami.WhereAmI()
            mail.Send("Error", body)
            fmt.Println(body)
            return
        }
        transaction, err = instance.OnFlashLoan(auth, common.HexToAddress(wallet.FlashLoanContractAddress), token0, amount, big.NewInt(0), packedData)
        if err != nil {
            tx := ""
            if transaction != nil {
                tx = transaction.Hash().Hex()
            }
            e := err.Error() + whereami.WhereAmI()
            mail.Send("Error swapping:"+tx, e)
            fmt.Println(e) //<---------- Error swapping: no contract code at given address
            return
        }
    } else {
        s := "No API set:"
        mail.Send("Error API", s)
        fmt.Println(s)
        return
    }

    radarSwap.TransactionHash = transaction.Hash().Hex()

    if !runtime.IsDEV() {
        err := db.InsertTrade(radarSwap)
        if err != nil {
            //mail.Send("Error inserting swap:", err.Error())
            fmt.Println("Error inserting swap:", err)
        }
    }
}

